# Wordpress postmeta comma separated field to new table/column?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a field in table wp_postmeta, meta_value column in mysql database containing comma separated color codes like this: **#6f2b34,#edfa00,#1f200a"**.
Can i make a new table from it like this in php/mysql?

Id      color

0       #6f2b34 
1       #edfa00
2       #1f200a

Or at least a column to an existing table and each color to be a field?
Thank you!

Comment: How many color codes you have in your table right now ?

Comment: Right now there are 10-20. But I know that there will be many soon and I will need to make some queries on them in mysql, so I really need a column filled with 1 color each row.